# Bulk mutations using GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I am consuming a third-party GraphQL API and I need to perform several mutations. There is a way to iterate over a list and call the desired mutation? Something like:

```
mutation ($inputs: [EntityInput!]) {
  // iterate over $inputs and ... {
    entityUpdate(input: $input) {
      entity {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do what you're asking using GraphQL syntax alone. However, you could use string interpolation and [field aliases](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Field-Alias) to achieve the same result. Here's what that would look like using JavaScript:

```js
const inputs = [...]
const variableDefinitions = inputs
  .map((_input, index) => `$input${index}: EntityInput!`)
  .join(', ')
const selectionSet = inputs
  .map((_input, index) => `
    entityUpdate${index}: entityUpdate(input: $input${index}) {
      entity {
        id
      }
    }
  `)
  .join('/n')
const query = `
  mutation (${variableDefinitions}) {
    ${selectionSet}
  }
}
`
const variables = inputs.reduce((acc, input, index) => {
  acc[`input${index}`] = input
  return acc
}, {})
```

This results in a map of variables like `$input0`, `$input1`, etc. and a responding query like:

```
mutation ($input0: EntityInput!, $input1: EntityInput) {
  entityUpdate0: entityUpdate(input: $input0) {
      entity {
        id
      }
    }
  }
  entityUpdate1: entityUpdate(input: $input1) {
      entity {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can utilize a fragment to reduce the duplication among the selection sets and reduce the size of your payload.

Additionally, some servers (like [Hot Chocolate](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v10/execution-engine/batching#request-batching)) support batching operations inside a single HTTP request. If the server you're querying supports this feature, that would be an alternative way of accomplishing the same goal.